# Saving fingerprint template to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

I have U.are.u fingerprint 4500 reader, currently the sdk that came with it saves the fingerprint template as a file instead of to a database. I would like to save it into a database and also be able to verify the finger from the database. That is the code below

```
namespace Enrollment
{
    /* NOTE: This form is a base for the EnrollmentForm and the VerificationForm,
        All changes in the CaptureForm will be reflected in all its derived forms.
    */
    public partial class CaptureForm : Form, DPFP.Capture.EventHandler
    {
        public CaptureForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected virtual void Init()
        {
            try
            {
                Capturer = new DPFP.Capture.Capture();              // Create a capture operation.

                if ( null != Capturer )
                    Capturer.EventHandler = this;                   // Subscribe for capturing events.
                else
                    SetPrompt("Can't initiate capture operation!");
            }
            catch
            {               
                MessageBox.Show("Can't initiate capture operation!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);            
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Process(DPFP.Sample Sample)
        {
            // Draw fingerprint sample image.
            DrawPicture(ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample));
        }

        protected void Start()
        {
            if (null != Capturer)
            {
                try
                {
                    Capturer.StartCapture();
                    SetPrompt("Using the fingerprint reader, scan your fingerprint.");
                }
                catch
                {
                    SetPrompt("Can't initiate capture!");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Stop()
        {
            if (null != Capturer)
            {
                try
                {
                    Capturer.StopCapture();
                }
                catch
                {
                    SetPrompt("Can't terminate capture!");
                }
            }
        }

    #region Form Event Handlers:

        private void CaptureForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Init();
            Start();                                                // Start capture operation.
        }

        private void CaptureForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Stop();
        }
    #endregion

    #region EventHandler Members:

        public void OnComplete(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, DPFP.Sample Sample)
        {
            MakeReport("The fingerprint sample was captured.");
            SetPrompt("Scan the same fingerprint again.");
            Process(Sample);
        }

        public void OnFingerGone(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
        {
            MakeReport("The finger was removed from the fingerprint reader.");
        }

        public void OnFingerTouch(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
        {
            MakeReport("The fingerprint reader was touched.");
        }

        public void OnReaderConnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
        {
            MakeReport("The fingerprint reader was connected.");
        }

        public void OnReaderDisconnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
        {
            MakeReport("The fingerprint reader was disconnected.");
        }

        public void OnSampleQuality(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback CaptureFeedback)
        {
            if (CaptureFeedback == DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.Good)
                MakeReport("The quality of the fingerprint sample is good.");
            else
                MakeReport("The quality of the fingerprint sample is poor.");
        }
    #endregion

        protected Bitmap ConvertSampleToBitmap(DPFP.Sample Sample)
        {
            DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion Convertor = new DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion();  // Create a sample convertor.
            Bitmap bitmap = null;                                                           // TODO: the size doesn't matter
            Convertor.ConvertToPicture(Sample, ref bitmap);                                 // TODO: return bitmap as a result
            return bitmap;
        }

        protected DPFP.FeatureSet ExtractFeatures(DPFP.Sample Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose Purpose)
        {
            DPFP.Processing.FeatureExtraction Extractor = new DPFP.Processing.FeatureExtraction();  // Create a feature extractor
            DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback feedback = DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.None;
            DPFP.FeatureSet features = new DPFP.FeatureSet();
            Extractor.CreateFeatureSet(Sample, Purpose, ref feedback, ref features);            // TODO: return features as a result?
            if (feedback == DPFP.Capture.CaptureFeedback.Good)
                return features;
            else
                return null;
        }

        protected void SetStatus(string status)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Function(delegate() {
                StatusLine.Text = status;
            }));
        }

        protected void SetPrompt(string prompt)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Function(delegate() {
                Prompt.Text = prompt;
            }));
        }
        protected void MakeReport(string message)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Function(delegate() {
                StatusText.AppendText(message + "\r\n");
            }));
        }

        private void DrawPicture(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Function(delegate() {
                Picture.Image = new Bitmap(bitmap, Picture.Size);   // fit the image into the picture box
            }));
        }

        private DPFP.Capture.Capture Capturer;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to save the fingerprint template into an SQL database

Comment: There are countless examples about how to save data using C# and SQL Server -- posting 200 lines of code is not a good question.  Please read the FAQ about making a good question and come back when you actually have a question.  Just having a job to do is not a reason to post a question here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not a job, it's my final year project. I really need help, every time i come here no one just want to help me, always saying i should do this or do that first, can't someone just help me pleaseee?

Comment: The finger print is the variable sample in OnComplete().  Save it in database as binary data using varbinary(MAX).

Comment: so instead of complaining that I'm saying you should do this or that why don't you just do this or that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the DB interaction code, so actually no one can help you out. To guide you on what you want, do the below:-

1. The `Process` function is the place where you can save the finger print to DB.
   Save the converted `Bitmap` or directly `DPFP.Sample` format as binary data or byte array to DB. Choice depends on your design. Will suggest for `Bitmap` for easy maintenance.

   `protected virtual void Process(DPFP.Sample Sample) {`

   ```
       // Draw fingerprint sample image.
       var fingerprintBMP = DrawPicture(ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample));
       //Call a function eg. SaveToDB(fingerprintBMP) to save to DB
   ```

   `}`
2. `SaveToDB` function should not be a problem. Refer [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database).